# In a unreal conditional sentence, what do we do if we want to express continuous tense?

Tags: tense, conditionals

In a unreal conditional sentence, what do we do if we want to express continuous tense?

**Unreal present continuous**

**Example 1**

> I would cut off the power if he "were" watching the TV at this time.

**Unreal past continuous**

**Example 2**

> I would have cut off the power if he "had been" watching the TV at that time.

Comment: What is your question about these forms? Both examples are valid.

Answer (score 0):

> I would have cut off the power if he "was" watching the TV at that time.